# Applying a sort to NSArray of custom objects

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sorting

I have an array of custom objects (really an NSSet stored in Core Data which becomes an NSArray with AllObjects) and each of these custom objects is a `ListItem`. Each `ListItem` belongs to a `List`, which has a uniqueID. Each `ListItem` has a different uniqueID which is the uniqueID of the `List` it belongs to + a number. So if the id of my `List` object is @"foo", then its `ListItems` would each have the property ListItem1.id = @"foo0", ListItem2.id = @"foo1", ListItem3.id = "foo2" etc..

So, how can I sort my array of custom objects based on the number that is appended to this uniqueID on each ListItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(ListItem *obj1, ListItem *obj2){
    return [obj1.id compare:obj2.id];
}];
```

Comment: and that, people, is why they call him executor21